# Yapp / yacc / bison - syntax

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm trying to write a parser using Perl Yapp, which to my understanding is mostly identical to yacc/bison.
The input which gives me troubles looks like this:

```
interface someName
  description "bla"
  ip address 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.128
ip default-gateway 1.2.3.123
```

My syntax is this:

```
command:
   INTERFACE IDENTIFIER if_attrs
 | IP DEFAULT_GATEWAY IP_ADDRESS
;

if_attrs: # empty
 | if_attrs if_attr
;

if_attr:
  DESCRIPTION STRING
| IP ADDRESS IP_ADDRESS IP_ADDRESS
;
```

Of course both the input and the entire syntax is much more complex, but these are the essential parts.

Generating the tokens works (so far I do not care for the indention), but running it complains about "DEFAULT_GATEWAY".
Yapp also reports a S/R conflict at the state after reading "IP" which somehow makes sense to me, however I cound not find a solution.
I already read a lot about precedence tricks and tried a few things but without success.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that your grammar requires two tokens of lookahead, which puts it out of scope for an LALR(1) parser. (The "1" indicates that lookahead is limited to one token.)

That doesn't make the language LALR(2). There is no such thing as an LALR(2) language because every language with an LALR(2) grammar also has an LALR(1) grammar. Moreover, there is an algorithm which can transform an LALR(2) grammar into an LALR(1) grammar, and even make it possible to recover the parse tree which would have been generated by the LALR(2) grammar if you had an implementation.

Unfortunately, the grammars generated by this transformation are very bulky and hard to read, and have a lot of productions with the same semantic actions. Also, there are few implementations of the transformation, because a more effective strategy is to use a more general parsing algorithm. Bison itself can be asked to generate a GLR parser, and in Perl there is [Jeffrey Kegler's Marpa parser](http://jeffreykegler.github.io/Marpa-web-site/), among others. But I'm going to assume that you don't want to change parser generator.

The basic nature of the LALR(2)⇒LALR(1) transformation is to store the first lookahead token as part of the semantic value. This effectively shifts the parser one token into the future. If you're doing this by hand, that transformation is only needed for the non-terminals which actually need two tokens of lookahead, which in your case is basically the top-level non-terminal which represents a list of commands.

For now, I'm not going to write that out, either. Instead, I'm going to provide two simpler and possibly more maintainable hacks.

#### Disambiguate `ip` in the lexer

This is the way that most yacc-like processors handle the optional `;` in grammar descriptions. (I don't know if the semicolon is optional in yapp, but it certainly is in yacc and bison.) In the BNF syntax, an identifier token is unambiguously a left-hand side if it is followed by a `:`, but a naive implementation is LR(2), as with your grammar; the previous definition can't be closed until the `:` is seen. To get around this problem, the lexer recognises an identifier followed by a `:` as a different token type. Similarly, your lexer could recognise the two token sequence `ip default-gateway` as a single token. That assumes that there is nowhere else in the grammar where `ip` could be immediately followed by `default-gateway`, or that if it is, it can be parsed as though it were a single world.

That complicates the lexer a bit (particularly if you allow comments between the two keywords) but if you only have a few phrases which have to be recognised that way it is probably not too bad.

#### Build up the interface command on the fly

Here, the top-level non-terminal is split into two possibilities:

- **closed**, meaning that the last command cannot be extended,
- **open**, meaning that the last command is an interface command and a following `if_attr` clause should be appended.
  The **open** non-terminal's semantic value includes the possibly-incomplete interface command as part of its semantic value.

This is also based on a strategy for parsing BNF, in which a single identifier is just retained in the semantic value for the list of productions until it becomes clear whether it is to be added to the right-hand side of the last production or it is the left-hand side of a new production.

I haven't programmed in Perl for many years, so I wrote the semantic actions as pseudo-code. Sorry.

```perl
# A list of commands
closed_program:
   %empty
 | closed_program unambiguous_command {
       push($_[1], $_[2]); # Add the command to the end of the list
   }
 | open_program unambigous_command {
       push($_[1]{"list"}, $_[1]{"saved"});
                           # The saved command is now complete
       push($_[1]{"list"}, $_[2]);
                           # Also add the new complete command
   }

# Semantic value has two attributes:
# * "list" is a list of commands
# * "saved" is an interface command 
open_program:
   ​closed_program interface_identifier {
    ​# return {list => $_[1], saved => $_[2]}
  ​ }
 ​| open_program if_attr {
    ​# add $_[2] to the "saved" entry of $_[1]
  ​ }

unambiguous_command:
   ​default_gateway_command
 | ... # other commands which cannot be clauses
;

default_gateway_command:
   ​IP DEFAULT_GATEWAY IP_ADDRESS
;

# Action needs to create a new interface command
# with an empty list of attributes
interface_identifier:
  ​INTERFACE IDENTIFIER
;

# Action creates an attribute (however that is represented)
# which will be added to the attribute list
if_attr:
   ​DESCRIPTION STRING
 | IP ADDRESS IP_ADDRESS IP_ADDRESS
;
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. I stripped both input and grammar to exactly this plus one recursive rule (there are multiple input lines):
  line: # empty | line command ;
Still fails.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of a much simpler problem. Sorry. I'll replace this with a more complicated solution. :-)

Comment: @tge12345 I hope that is helpful. And sorry again about the confusion.

Comment: Many thx first of all! I will probably go the lexer-based way - simpler.
The other option (admittedly I don't understand it entirely - though it's late here) works but not anymore with two interface sections in the input. Unless I messed sth up. Challenge? :-)

Comment: @tge12345: Yeah, it's a simplification which is dependent on the particular nature of the conflict. So more options probably means more work. The lexer hack is indeed simpler which is why it's more common; it's almost always the preferred option if all you need to do is recognize multi-word keyphrases. The main reason I like the other solution is that it extends to larger lookahead. For example, bison lets you write `expr[result]: expr[numer] '/' expr[denom] { $result = $numer / $denom; }`; getting that right with the lexer trick is a pain (although that's the way bison does it).

Comment: When I have a bit more time I'll try to remember enough Perl to actually write the actions so I can debug it,

Comment: Don't bother the Perl actions, this is something I and everybody can try out then - just see what tokens there are. Also, yapp has good verbosity and says which rules and states are involved. My personal problem is rather the grammar.
The lexer-approach works nicely btw!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which might be simpler than rici's approach is to parse the lines independently and then try to combine them together afterwards.  You might have something like:

```
input: /*empty*/ | input line ;

line:
    INTERFACE IDENTIFIER '\n' {
        lines.push_back(Interface(...      }
  | IP DEFAULT_GATEWAY IP_ADDRESS '\n' {
        lines.push_back(DefaultGateway(...     }
  | DESCRIPTION STRING '\n' {
        if (lines.back().isInterface()) {
            lines.back().addDescription(...
        } else {
            error("description not associated with interface"); } }
  | IP ADDRESS IP_ADDRESS IP_ADDRESS '\n' {
        if (lines.back().isInterface()) {
            lines.back().addAddress(...
        } else {
            error("address not associated with interface"); } }
;
```

forgive the pseudo-code actions in no particular language, but hopefully they give an idea about what is needed here.  This works particularly well with strongly line-oriented syntax -- thus the explicit `'\n'` tokens here, which are not actually necessary in this case, but might be useful in other cases

Comment: Interesting view - thx! In my case it's not clear, possibly the indentation denotes some kind of logical blocks (no confirmation yet) - if not it would be line-oriented.
I also experimented with an INDENT token, but in the end I went for the lexer-based way as simplest and safe (whether indent or not).